# How to fix long delays in an app with Bitmaps?

Tags: android, bitmap, delay, lag

I'm making an android app where you can add items to a `RecyclerList` and the items contain an image and some text but the app takes a long time to start up and resume due to those Bitmaps.

The way my app works is this: When you add a new items to the `RecyclerView` it prompts you for an image and then I decode that into a `Bitmap` (I reduce the image size) and save it in that Item's data model. Then on `onBindViewHolder()` I get the image from the Item and add it to the `Layout`. Also on `onCreate()` I iterate through all the saved `Bitmaps` (Saved in a folder) and initialize my list from there but this takes a relatively long time.

How can I make the Bitmaps load faster so that the app won't have long delays on `onCreate()` and `onResume()` (This one is because of the `RecyclerView`)?

What I thought about was maybe not saving the `Bitmaps` in the item at all since I'm saving a `UUID` and the `UUID` is the `Bitmap's` file name so this way I only load the images in `onBindViewHolder()` and then I can immediately `recycle()` them but I don't know if this will work.

I also read something about `LruCache` but I didn't really understand it, can it help in my case?

If there's any more information I should post about my app so answering this will be easier please tell me.

EDIT: The images are prompted and are from the user's gallery.

Comment: "How can I make the Bitmaps load faster" -- since you have not told us anything about where these bitmaps come from, that will be difficult for anyone to answer. I strongly suggest the use of one of the many, many [image loading libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), such as [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). These libraries are designed to solve these sorts of issues, through asynchronous image loading, in-memory caching, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare I will edit my post and also check out Picasso. But should I save the Bitmaps in the Item's data model? Or, with those libraries and in general I shouldn't?

Comment: If you switch to a library that offers an in-memory cache, use that, and have your model objects hold the path/`Uri`/whatever that you used to load the image in the first place. When you tell the image loading library to load the image (again), it will check the cache and give you the image from there if it is available.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried removing all the code from `onBindViewHolder()` just to see if it will still lag and it STILL lags when there's nothing there. What should I do to find the source of the lag?

Comment: You can try [method tracing](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-methodtrace.html). Or, if you have not done so already, enable `StrictMode` to yell at you about doing disk I/O on the main application thread (it should already crash your app if you try doing network I/O on the main application thread).